# selecting columns randomly using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need to implement a question answer form using php , I need to select the question along with the option values.in a way that the option values should be random.

such as 
Select quest,option1,option2,option3 from Questtable ;
how can get the option1,option2,option3 in a random order for each request, any way can we implement using mysql. ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Don't select random columns. Adjust your database model in such a way where you don't have to randomize column selection, meaning save questions and answers in separate tables as *rows*.

Comment: It's hard to answer to this question without providing any information about your db structure. Could you tell us a bit more about it ?

Comment: it's difficult to try something that not exists

Comment: This is a classic example where someone is looking a solution to the *wrong* problem. The approach is bad. If you want to randomize (using MySQL) the options you'll display in a web form, you don't save them in columns, you save them in rows. If you want to stick to column-based layout (for some unknown reason, seeing you can't add *new* options easily) then it's much more efficient to fetch the entire row and use some server-side language to shuffle options. Depending on what you want to do, you only have 2 choices here. Knowing that MySQL supports RAND() only on rows - the answer is clear.

Comment: i GOT IT IT CAN BE PERFORMED ARRAY SHUFFLE FUNCTION, CREATING ARRAY FROM THE COLUMNS VALUES. IT CANT BE DONT WITH MYSQL QUERY THE WAY I THOUGHT.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shuffle.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a MySQL query to do this ain't possible, but you can make php randomize the output.
Write the options to an empty array, then randomize the array.

If you like to do it with MySQL you have to make 2 tables, one containing the questions and once containing the answers, 1 answer per row.

Then you can do:

```
SELECT option FROM tbl_answers WHERE questionId = X ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: The other way we can do is accept the value in an array, the three option in a arry and print it randomly , right, but i think is there any way we can eliminate this section using mysql

Comment: If you like to do it with MySQL you have to make 2 tables, one containing the questions and once containing the answers, 1 answer per row.

Then you can do:

SELECT option FROM tbl_answers WHERE questionId = X ORDER BY RAND()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RAND()`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I think is not the answer to this question :-)

Comment: RAND is used to fetch rand om records right ,

Comment: @anoopps yea, so what you really need?

Comment: @anoopps note that this will work only if your table is an "option table" containing all the possible options. Without informations on the database structure, we can just speculate and give approximative answers.

Comment: ok, so can we do if ther are two table one for question second options

Comment: Yep, with a link to the question for each option entry in the option table.

Comment: YES, you are absolutely right , and randomly selecting the columns with the question id right , thanks . This is the right way

Comment: this could b e an alternative, IT CAN also BE PERFORMED ARRAY SHUFFLE FUNCTION, CREATING ARRAY FROM THE COLUMNS VALUES. IT CANT BE DONT WITH MYSQL QUERY THE WAY I THOUGHT.

Answer (score 0):

No. Is not possible with only mysql

You can do a `SELECT quest,option1,option2,option3` and shuffle via php

Comment: i think so, thought there might any function like rand() from records

Comment: downvoter please explain. @anoopps is not possible only via mysql

Comment: It is possible read the base suggestion s.lenders

Answer (score 0):

Although you should change your table design as already mentioned you can try this very crude one (but crude design leads to crude solutions)

```
SELECT
  quest,
  CASE rval WHEN 0 THEN option1 WHEN 1 THEN option2 WHEN 2 THEN option3 END option_1,
  CASE rval WHEN 0 THEN option2 WHEN 1 THEN option3 WHEN 2 THEN option1 END option_2,
  CASE rval WHEN 0 THEN option3 WHEN 1 THEN option1 WHEN 2 THEN option2 END option_3
FROM (
SELECT
  *,
  FLOOR( RAND() * 3 ) rval
FROM tbl_answers ) tmp
```

And please: "**Don't do that at home!**"